# Is it true that $H_n(C_{*}(X)^{nor} \otimes M) \cong H_n(C_{*}^{\neq}(X) \otimes M)$?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I am reading a book that uses a lot of homological algebra and I am not familiar with the tools of it. To prove a part of a theorem I suspect the following must be true.

Let $X$ be an infinite $G$-set. Consider a chain complex $(C_{*}(X), \partial)$ where $C_n(X)$ is the free abelian group generated by $X^{n+1}$ and 
$\partial((x_0,\ldots,x_n))=\sum_i (-1)^{i} (x_0, \ldots, x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, \ldots, x_n)$.

> If $C_n^{\neq}(X)$ is free abelian group generated by the set $\{(x_0, \ldots,x_n)~|~x_i \neq x_j \forall i \neq j\}$ and $C_n^D(X)$ is free abelian group generated by the set $\{(x_0, \ldots, x_n)~|~x_i =x_{i+1} ~\textrm{for some}~0 \leq i \leq n-1\}$, then is it true that for any $G$ module $M$, $H_n(C_n ^{\neq} (X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}M) \cong H_n(C_n^{nor}(X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} M)?$

Here $C_n^{nor}(X)= C_n(X)/C_n^{D}(X)$ and is called *normalized complex.*

Comment: Is the definition of $C_n^D(X)$ correct? If so, I don't understand how $C_*^{nor}(X)$ is a chain complex, as $\partial$ doesn't map $C_n^D(X)$ into $C_{n-1}^D(X)$.

Comment: Jeremy Rickard: Sorry, I have corrected it.

Comment: I still don't think that there's a well-defined differential, since $\partial((x_0,\dots,x_n))$ is in $C_{n-1}^D(X)$ only if $x_i=x_{i+1}$ for at least *two* values of $i$.

Comment: Jeremy Rickard: It is well-defined. $$\partial((x_0, \ldots, x_{i-1},x_i,x_i,x_{i+2},\ldots, x_n)) = \sum_{j=0} ^{j=i-1} (-1)^j (x_0, \ldots, \hat{x_j}, \ldots, x_{i-1},x_i,x_i,x_{i+2}, \ldots,x_n) + \sum_{j= i+2} ^{j=n} (-1)^j (x_0, \ldots,x_i,x_i,x_{i+2},\ldots, \hat{x_j}, \ldots, x_n),$$ here by $\hat{x_j}$ I mean to remove it. Thus $\partial(C_n ^D(X))\subset C_{n-1} ^D (X)$.

Comment: Ah, yes, OK! Sorry.